# Fecha en un TextBox C#

Tags: c#

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con esta pequeñita pero inquieta duda.Tengo un `Form` con un un `DataGridView`, el cual me trae valores almacenados en mi base de datos de ciertos campos que al realizar una búsqueda, se van a mostrar en ciertos `TextBox` dentro del mismo `Form`. Un `TextBox` en especifico se llama `vence` que corresponde al `txtbox7`, lo que busco es que una vez arrojado el valor `vence` (fecha) dentro del `txtbox7`,y a su vez este cuando se modifique, le indique al usuario si es un formato correcto, `dd//mm//yyyy`

Gracias.

Este es mi código:

```
  private void Btn10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txtbox7.Text)) //hasta aqui va bien, ya que si no hay nada dentro del txtbox arroja el mensaje en pantalla.
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Capture el Id de prestamo del cual desea actualizar la fecha de vencimiento.");
                return;
            }
            // segun yo aqui, si el valor que introzca el usuario es en ese //tipo de formato deberia mostrar el mensaje,
// de poner fecha en formato correcot.
//Datetime al final lo marca en rojo y dice : Generalmente representa una //instancia de tiempo, generalmente representa una fecha del dia. Mi fecha se //almacena en el txtbox7.

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Txtbox7.Text,"300/13/19999", null,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime fecha ))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Capture fecha en formato correcto");
            }    
             // si el valor es capturado correctamente se acutaliza la informacion.
                using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
                {
                    conexion.Open();
                    string query = "Update Tb1 Set Vence = @Vence Where IdPrestamo=@IdPrestamo";
                    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vence", Convert.ToDateTime(Txtbox7.Text));
                    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdPrestamo", TxtBox1.Text);
                    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fecha actualizada correctamente.");
                return;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta esta bien, pero no entiendo que parte de tu codigo tiene el problema. Ese tryparse sobre el datetime tiene un formato raro no? Aparte de eso, en realidad, la fecha no estaria mejor en un control datetimepicker? de esa forma, no tenes que andar validando el formato ni el usuario pelearse con el...

Comment: Tambien podrias usar el  MaskedTexbox y en propiedades le das el formato dd/mm/yyy

Answer (score 1):

No uses un TextBox para mostrar una fecha usa el control `DateTimePicker`

[C# DateTimePicker Control](http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-datetimepicker.htm)

Este control lo veras en la `toolbox`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No te compliques tanto. Haz doble click en el cuadro del textbox dentro del formulario y agrega la siguiente linea.
Me.(aquí y sin paréntesis, coloca el nombre que le asignaste a tu textbox)= Date
Saludos

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)